# Simple question about TeXworks

Tags: texworks

I'm a beginner to TeXworks. I'm curious about how I can increase line space when typing text? I mean can I adjust line space or alignment of text so it looks like more comfortable when working with it? Is there a setting I could change in the preferences?

I'm still not accustomed to typing text like the attached picture.

I hope you can understand my question despite my poor English. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Line spacing in the editor window cannot be adjusted by the user in Texworks. It's only a [feature request](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/124). There are other [TeX editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) with this feature, for example [TexStudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5281/43189).

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help a bit but in general, you might want to take a look on more powerful editors. My choice is TeXstudio which supports line spacing in % as well as font size, scrolled zooming (like in Word), and many other settings.

But back to TeXworks:

The answer to your question on line spacing seems to be "no". At least, I could not find that. But there are other things you might tweak to your needs.

Just go to "Edit->Preferences..." and you will open a pop-up called "TeXworks Preferences". In the panel "General", you might want to increase the size of icons, just in case, those are too small for you. In the panel "Editor" you have some configuration possibilities regarding your text window and the used font. You may switch the font and its size which both might effect the line spacing as well. Just give it a try. In this panel, you may also change the default indent (Tab width) and toggle on syntax coloring and so on. Just set everything to your needs.

It might be that you will have to restart TeXworks in order to see some changes. And you mustn't be afraid on doing any harm as there is a "Restore Defaults" button in the lower left corner which will bring you back from Comic Sans to whatever the maintainers of that editor see fit.

[image]

Comment: What's scrolled zooming? (I don't use Word so that doesn't help. Or, rather, I barely use Word very, very rarely and very, very briefly with great difficulty. If LibreOffice does it, I'd probably understand if you explained that way.)

Comment: @cfr I should not invent phrasings... I meant that the font size in the editor increases when pressing Ctrl and scrolling the mouse wheel at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I honestly thought this was some new whizzy Word thing ;).